# Converting characters formats to dates returns NAs

Tags: r, date

I'm looking to convert the Dates which are currently in chr format

| Date |
| --- |
| July2021 |
| August2021 |

to

| Date |
| --- |
| 2021-07 |
| 2021-08 |

when I run the code below my Date column are all NAs

```r
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%B%Y")
```

Comment: Those are not dates. A date *always* includes a day of the month. You could of course just add a day to the character string to make these valid dates.

Answer (score 0):

This is for your reference. Add 01 so that it becomes a date

```
sampleD= "August2021"
substr(as.Date( paste0('01',sampleD), "%d%B%Y"),1,7)
```

Result:

```
'2021-08'
```

Comment: The `01` should be quoted (i.e. `"01"`); otherwise it is recognized as numeric `1` in R.

Comment: As suggested, "01" is better than 01.